# How to add a new custom Content Type without disruption?

Tags: content-type, custom

I need to add a new custom Content Type to an existing SharePoint Intranet site but I want to make sure I do not disrupt any of the data or web parts on the site.  What is the best way to go about this - is it to do a Feature Upgrade, or to retract and re-deploy the Content Types wsp?

Answer (score 0):

If it's new you have not problem to add it.
Otherwise if you want add new column on your old content type you have to upgrade it and you can set a default value on those new columns.

Off course, to be sure to avoid any kind of problem, before deploy in production you should deploy the wsp in a stage environment.

Comment: Thanks Salvatore. I was just worried that if I retract the content type wsp to deploy a new one, that it might delete existing data on the site.

Comment: If you are in production why you want delete the old one for a new one? that is dangerous. Better, IMHO, is update the old content type. You are able to add and remove the old columns.

Comment: I don't want to delete anything, just add a new custom Content Type.

Comment: So you can add a new one and add the new one to the list or update the old one